# Angular - Can´t return array to ng-select

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown. I need to fill this with the array values, the problem is the select doesn´t take this values. If i print the array with console.log works fine, but when i try to send this to the component, i don´t know why, the values doesn´t sent.

In HTML if i use {{}} to print values does´t show anything.

I use  a bit *strange* code to create this array, I pair keys with text, maybe the error is here.

TS (This is the strange code)

```
 perfilesTodos: Profile[] = [];
  data: string[] = [
    "Arson",
    "Administrador de entidad",
    "Administrador de grupo",
    "Gestor",
    "Instalador"
  ];
  this.usersCtrl.getProfiles().subscribe(response => {
      response["body"].forEach((id: number) => {
        this.perfilesTodos.push({
          id,
          descripcion: this.data[id - 1]
        });
      });

    });
```

console.log(this.perfilesTodos); return

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, descripcion: "Arson"}
1: {id: 2, descripcion: "Administrador de entidad"}
2: {id: 3, descripcion: "Administrador de grupo"}
3: {id: 4, descripcion: "Gestor"}
4: {id: 5, descripcion: "Instalador"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="profile">{{'profile-placeholder' | translate}}</label>
      <ng-select [items]="perfilesTodos" name="perfiles" bindLabel="descripcion" placeholder="{{'profile-placeholder' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="perfiles">
      </ng-select>
  </div>
```

So the question is: How can i fill the select with this array?

Comment: can you link  which package have you used ?

Comment: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR

below change is required :

```
this.usersCtrl.getProfiles().subscribe(response => {

      let tempArr = [];
      response["body"].forEach((id: number) => {
      tempArr.push({
          id,
          descripcion: this.data[id - 1]
        });
       this.perfilesTodos = [...tempArr];
      });
```

**Why my code is not working ?**

As per the documentation :

> Ng-select component implements OnPush change detection which means the
>   dirty checking checks for immutable data types. That means if you do
>   object mutations like:

```
this.items.push({id: 1, name: 'New item'})
```

> Component will not detect a change. Instead you need to do:

```
this.items = [...this.items, {id: 1, name: 'New item'}];
```

> This will cause the component to detect the change and update. Some
>   might have concerns that this is a pricey operation, however, it is
>   much more performant than running ngDoCheck and constantly diffing the
>   array.

read here  : [Change detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select#change-detection)